# Как отправить сообщение на Viber?

Tags: php, java, android, c#, c++

Хочу со своего сайта или десктоп/мобайл приложения отправить сообщение на вайбер.

Есть ли такая возможность? Какими библиотеками пользоваться?

Answer (score 4):

Есть, но api закрытое. Вам необходимо заключить договор с Viber, чтобы иметь возможность отправлять сообщения.